# Visual Studio 2010 with NMAKE

Tags: visual-studio-2010, scons

I am trying to generate a Visual Studio 2010 solution with the SCons, using vs2010 for building arp32 lib with the help of NAMKE of vs2010, after a successful build we are getting last line.

Please see this log, any suggestion will be appreciated.

```
1>------ Build started: Project: cipp, Configuration: cipp_algo_ti_arp32_debug Win32 ------
1>Build started 9/28/2016 6:50:03 AM.
1>Build:
1>  Starting SCons 
1>  TRIDIP::::::::::::::::::float(num) 10.0
1>  Path not found - D:\VS2010_test\CIPP\04_Engineering\03_Workspace\algo\cipp_sim\cipp_evm_hil\vme\generic\evm_sw
1>  
1>  targets being built/cleaned : cipp_algo_ti_arp32_debug
1>  running with -j 1
1>  command line defines : 
1>  verbose output :  0
1>EXEC : error : Compiler Personality file is not found
1>EXEC : error : Compiler Personality file is not found
1>EXEC : error : Compiler Personality file is not found
1>EXEC : error : Compiler Personality file is not found
1>EXEC : error : Compiler Personality file is not found
1>  TRIDIP::::::::::::::::::float(num) 10.0
1>  TRIDIP::::::::::::::::::float(num) 10.0
1>  TRIDIP::::::::::::::::::float(num) 8.0
1>  TRIDIP::::::::::::::::::float(num) 8.0
1>  TRIDIP::::::::::::::::::float(num) 8.0
1>  TRIDIP::::::::::::::::::float(num) 8.0
1>  TRIDIP::::::::::::::::::float(num) 8.0
1>  TRIDIP::::::::::::::::::float(num) 8.0
1>  scons: `cipp_algo_ti_arp32_debug' is up to date.
1>  
1>  Build succeeded.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.MakeFile.Targets(38,5): error MSB3073: The command "echo Starting SCons && cd D:\VS2010_test\CIPP\04_Engineering\03_Workspace\algo\cipp && scons.bat -Q -j 1 skip_ide_generation=1 build_from_ide=1 build_from_vs=1  -C "D:\VS2010_test\CIPP\04_Engineering\03_Workspace\algo\cipp" -f SConstruct "cipp_algo_ti_arp32_debug"  2>&1 | ..\..\..\02_Development_Tools\scons_tools\gnutools\sed.exe -e "s/:\([0-9]\+\):[0-9]\+:/(\1) : /" -e "s/, line \([0-9]\+\):/(\1) : /"& if exist errorlevel.txt (for /f %%A in (errorlevel.txt) do exit /b %%A)" exited with code -1.
1>
1>Build FAILED.
1>
1>Time Elapsed 00:00:03.60
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: Looking at the log, the SCons build itself seems to have been successfull. You want to split up your long command line in the batch file, such that you can inspect the intermediate results and determine in which area the build actually fails. There seems to be a lot of error code handling and log file parsing going on. Find out which of these stages creates the error...

Comment: I tried removing every thing just scons -c for cleaning, after successful clean I am getting same C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.MakeFile.Targets(38,5): error MSB3073: